# Is there a way to publish protractor test results in confluence and have an overview?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, gitlab-ci, confluence

We run our protractor regression tests in gitlab CI and we have jasmine HTML reports. Right now it is only the QA team that monitors and checks failure if any.
But we would like to make it more visible. The devs have also asked us if we can make it visible in a single place instead of having to go to gitlab job and browse for artifacts.Also would it be possible to have an overview of pass/fail tests over time.
I'm not sure how and where to start. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `expose_as` keyword for artifacts. The full docs are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpose_as.

If you use `expose_as` with your artifacts, Gitlab CI will link them to any application Merge Request with the name you give in this field.

For example (from the docs):

```sh
test:
  script: ["echo 'test' > file.txt"]
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'artifact 1'
    paths: ['file.txt']
```

In this example, a Merge Request for this pipeline will have a link called "artifact 1" that opens the file "file.txt".

This also works for directories, but if there's more than one file it will open in the job's artifacts browser (like you currently do).

There are some caveats, like:

- If you use a variable in the artifacts `path` field, `expose_as` won't work
- Max of 10 artifacts can be exposed
- Glob patters won't work
- If Gitlab Pages is enabled, some file extensions will be automatically rendered using Pages (html, xml, txt, etc.).

Comment: It doesn't look like what I am looking for. I am looking for a dashboard kind of test report on a page we can display the result of the latest test run and/or test results over time to have an overview of the pass/fail status.

Comment: As of Gitlab 13.9, the only way to show test reports outside of the pipeline is to use the `expose_as` keyword to show it on Merge Requests. However, you could use Gitlab Pages to host the results manually (if the tests pass, upload the report to a Pages repo)

Comment: When exposing directories, I found paths need to end in a `/` or you just get "view 0 exposed artifacts"